# The action can't be completed because the folder or a file in it is open in another program

Tags: windows-7

I want to remove an unnecessary file from drive c:\ the message

> The action can't be completed because the folder or a file in it is
>   open in another program

Please help me how to remove it.

Comment: what sort of file?

Comment: Executive files

Comment: Executive? Or executable? It's probably a program thats running, a virus or something, close it down in task manager first then try and delete it

Comment: it is not open I have already closed it

Comment: it may have reopened, or it may be a virus which is still running, have you scanned your machine?

Comment: Yes I have scanned my machine it dose not have virus.

Answer (score 1):

That's pretty much what the error says: you can't delete the file because it is in use by another program.

The simplest way to solve the problem for an inexperienced user is to reboot the machine, then try to delete the file again.  If this does not work, try to reboot in Safe Mode (hit <kbd>F8</kbd> at boot) with the minimum number of services launched.

You can also try to identify the program (from the Task Manager) that's holding the lock and kill it, if you know what you're doing.

Answer (score 0):

To find and close the process that has the file open, please follow this steps:

Open resource monitor (Windows +R to open Run then type Resmon.exe)
Open the CPU tab in the monitor
Select all processes (not sure if this is needed, you can probably just search for the handle)
Expand "associated handles"
Search for the file you need
Close the process that has the handle